# Retrieve Data from database if new records added in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello i have gone through Long polling, websockets and APE, Ajax push, Ajax Pull. As the technology of websockets isnt yet much introduced in our World Wide Web now. i thought i would use the normal setInterval functions to check the database. this is for a chat application, my code :-

on **Home.php** :
*Javascript*:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function(){

var id = $id;  // this is the id of the last message inserted in the database

var data = 'id='+id;

$.ajax({

type : "POST",
url : "check.php",
data : data,
success : function(data){

if(data)
{
$(".comments").append(data);
}

}


});


},1000);
```

and **check.php**
*php code* :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id>'$id' ORDER BY id DESC");
$num2 = mysql_num_rows($get);
$get2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);
$id = $get2['id'];

if($num2!=0)
{


$username = $get2['username'];
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE username='$username'");
  $n = mysql_num_rows($a);
  $b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a);

   $file = $b['filename'];
   $pic = "<img src=\"images/" .$file. "\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\">";
 $name = $get2['fullname'];
$message = $get2['message'];

echo $pic.$message."<br/>";
}
else
{
}
```

if there is a new record inserted in the database it echo's out properly but then it doesnt update the $id in the home.php page so it sends the old id again and again and the comment gets appended again and again.

what i want is. for every interval . the $id of the home.php should be updated so that it sends only the present message id to the check.php page.

Comment: Sanitize your inputs! I can wipe out your db just by submitting check.php?id=';drop table messages;--

Comment: yea yea lol. i was first doin it as a testing thing n if everything would work out then would go into the security part ;-). anyways thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

I gues that the first code you've post is in your template of *home.php* and the **$id** then goes replaced with the real number of the last ID.

this works for the first time when the page is processed with PHP, but once downloaded on users machine, you only have to rely on JavaScript...
I'm not sure in which form you receive the data from check.php, but you need to do something like

```
id = data.id
data = 'id='+id;
```

Comment: its a div named with a class "comments" it gets appended ther. so wher do i have to do this ? i mean in wich part of my code ?